# OSGI Service reference

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle

Before I call service from another bundle I would like to search for this service availability because I will get NPE.

What is the proper way to search for a service?

```
ServiceReference serviceReference = bc.getServiceReference(someclass.class.getName());
            if (serviceReference == null)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Missing service someclass, please start bundle <name>");
            }
            else
            {
                kernelsManager = (someclass) bc.getService(serviceReference);
            }
```

I would like to shutdown the framework if the service is not found. What is the proper to to do this? Can I improve somehow the above example?

Answer (score 3):

This is not as easy as that in OSGi. As the bundle containing the service could be started after the bundle using the service you should account for that dynamic. Simply checking if the service is present at a single point in time is not good enough.

You can achieve this by using a ServiceTracker. If the service is added you initialize your own class that depends on it. If it goes down you stop it. If you have more than one service dependency this is quite complicated though.

So in bigger cases better use a framework like Declarative Services or blueprint that automates this for you.

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to the answer by Christian, note that shutting down the framework simply because a service is unavailable, is bad practice. OSGi is dynamic by design, meaning that services may come and go, so your bundle should be able to deal with the situation that a service is not (yet) available or disappears and re-appears. Otherwise, I really don't see the purpose of using OSGi in the first place.

Comment: One more question. How I can stop the bundle if service is not available?

Comment: Still not a good practice, you should track the service via declarative services or a `ServiceTracker`, but you can stop the bundle by using `Bundle.stop`.

Comment: If you use declarative services then your own class that depends on the external service will be started when it becomes available and stopped when the service goes away. Blueprint is not that dynamic but still can handle services coming and going.

Comment: As addidtion to Christian's comment: You definately should try to avoid using `ServiceTracker` and such and let a dependency injection framework do the work for you. You can choose from Declaratvice Services, Blueprint or iPOJO to name a few. My personal favorite is iPOJO, since it is much stronger than Declarative Services but does not try to hide dynamism as Blueprint does.